# f# p/invoke on GetClientRect with pointers works but not with OutAttribute

Tags: f#, pinvoke

I can get this to work:

```
[<DllImport("user32.dll")>]
extern bool GetClientRect(nativeint, RECT*)

let getClientRect hwnd =
    let mutable r = RECT()
    if GetClientRect(hwnd, &&r) = false then
        raise <| System.Exception("GetClientRect failed")
    r
```

But for whatever reason, this just leaves `r` zero'd, with no exception thrown:

```
[<DllImport("user32.dll")>]
extern bool GetClientRect(nativeint, [<Out>] RECT rect)

let getClientRect hwnd =
    let mutable r = RECT()
    if GetClientRect(hwnd, r) = false then
        raise <| System.Exception("GetClientRect failed")
    r
```

Of course, the problem with using pointers is that I get the warning `warning FS0051: The use of native pointers may result in unverifiable .NET IL code`, and understandably so.

What could I be missing?

Edit: Even though it's been answered already, for the record, the struct definition:

```
[<Struct>]
type RECT =
    val left:int
    val top:int
    val right:int
    val bottom:int
```

Comment: What is your definition of `RECT`? You likely have value-vs-reference type issues in the type definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not very well documented, but using the ampersand (&) symbol in an F# P/Invoke signature is the correct (and best) way to pass a value by reference. It compiles to the same type signature as a C# `ref` parameter; adding `[<Out>]` to the parameter gives the same signature as a C# `out` parameter.

```
[<DllImport("user32.dll")>]
extern bool GetClientRect(nativeint hWnd, [<Out>] RECT& rect)

let getClientRect hwnd =
    let mutable r : RECT = Unchecked.defaultOf<_>
    if GetClientRect(hwnd, &r) = false then
        raise <| System.Exception("GetClientRect failed")
    r
```

Notice that once you change the P/Invoke signature to use `byref<RECT>` instead of `nativeptr<RECT>`, you also need to change the address-of operator (&&) you used on `r` to a single ampersand (&).

Since you're only getting a value *out* of `GetClientRect`, it's a good practice to initialize the mutable result value to `Unchecked.defaultOf<_>` so it's clear that it's meant to be overwritten by `GetClientRect`.

EDIT: If changing the P/Invoke signature to use byref (&) doesn't work, you could also try explicitly specifying the marshalling behavior on the return type. The MSDN documentation for GetClientRect says it returns a BOOL, which is not quite the same as a .NET bool (BOOL is a 4-byte integer value).

If you want to try that:

```
[<DllImport("user32.dll")>]
extern [<return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>] bool GetClientRect(
    nativeint hWnd, [<Out>] RECT& rect)
```

Comment: Noting, of course, that this will only work if `RECT` is a struct.

Comment: For the record, in this case at least, specifying the marshalling on the return type didn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: @ildjarn What makes you say that? The ptr (*) operator is restricted to structs, but byref isn't.

Comment: bool parameters get the MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool) attribute by default, which is why you don't need to marshal it explicitly here.

Comment: That's true -- but it's considered good practice to explicitly apply the `MarshalAs` attribute to `bool` parameters or returns types, because there are a few different ways they can be marshalled: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182206.aspx